# Cannot call JNDI resource in persistence.xml file

Tags: java, postgresql, tomcat7, datasource, persistence.xml

Although it seems many users faced the same problem, I have to post my own issue, taking in account that for now, no suggestion from those already present worked for me. Or maybe am I missing something?

Here is my `persistence.xml` file (located uner `resources/META-INF/` directory, in a maven project):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd ">
    <persistence-unit name="brass-unit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <properties>
                <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource" value="java:/comp/env/jdbc/BrassDB"/> 
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

under `resources/META-INF` I also have `context.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <Resource name="jdbc/BrassDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
              driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver" 
              url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb" username="usr" password="pwd" 
              maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWait="-1"/>
</Context>
```

In the `web.xml` file I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>brass_directory_business</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list> 
<resource-ref>
    <description>db connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/BrassDB</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

Note on web.xml: sometimes I commented `resource-ref` tag, but the same behavior results.

Now, in my servlet, when I run this, everything works fine:

```
InitialContext ctx = null;
try {
    ctx = new InitialContext();
    if (ctx == null) {
        throw new Exception("no context!");
    }
    DataSource ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/BrassDB");
    if (ds == null) {
        throw new Exception("data source not found!");
    }
    Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
    ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM person");
    int n = 0;
    while (rs.next()) {
        n++;
    }
    System.out.println("rs length is: " + n);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But when I run this:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("brass-unit");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();       
em.createNamedQuery("Person.findAll", Person.class).getResultList();
```

I get this exception:

```
Mar 04, 2014 4:48:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [com.banco.Test] in context with path [/brass_directory_business] threw exception
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build entity manager factory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:54)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    at com.banco.Test.doPost(Test.java:34)
    at com.banco.Test.doGet(Test.java:27)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.hibernate.engine.jndi.JndiException: Unable to lookup JNDI name [java:/comp/env/jdbc/BrassDB]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.locate(JndiServiceImpl.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1885)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1843)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:399)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:73)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [java:/comp/env/jdbc/BrassDB] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [java:].
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:819)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:153)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:415)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.locate(JndiServiceImpl.java:114)
    ... 42 more
```

My `pom.xml` looks like:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    //......
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        //...
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
        //...
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I'm using tomcat 7.0.52 as server.
Does anyone have any suggestion how to solve my issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, it seems that this issue is a Hibernate problem. I just changed hibernate version to 4.2.7, and it works well.

Answer (score 1):

I have another idea:

1.Add `<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>` to your persistence.xml, `<persistence-unit>` elemet

2.Add the following to your persistence.xml, `<persistence-unit>`/`<properties>` element:

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:standalone"/>
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa"/>
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
```

Besides, try removing the `hibernate-core` dependency from your pom.xml.

Now you should be able to use the entitymanager. If you need the JDBC connection, just take it from the EntityManager instance (not the way you took it with JNDI).

Comment: I would like to have it specified as a `DataSource`, not as a `JDBC` connection. Anyway, as you can see, this is a Hibernate issue in the version that I used.